# how to pick data by key from dictionary array?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I try to pick data from array dictionary by key.
I can do it index number.
 but here is my dictionary  `[[String : AnyObject]]` what is the **key** store each element when i Deserializing  from json to dictionary.
because dictionary set **key value** pair and Each value from the dictionary is associated with a **unique key**.

Here is my Json :

```
{
  "photos":  {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "perpage": 500,
    "total": 36,
    "photo":  [
       {
        "id": "9671201784",
        "owner": "34507951@N07",
        "secret": "fb55a848bc",
        "server": "5494",
        "farm": 6,
        "title": "Burning Man 2013",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "url_m": "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5494/9671201784_fb55a848bc.jpg",
        "height_m": "333",
        "width_m": "500",
        "is_primary": 1,
        "has_comment": 0
      },
       {
        "id": "16553346708",
        "owner": "116399434@N04",
        "secret": "092f304f0e",
        "server": "7630",
        "farm": 8,
        "title": "Burning Man",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "url_m": "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7630/16553346708_092f304f0e.jpg",
        "height_m": "244",
        "width_m": "500",
        "is_primary": 0,
        "has_comment": 0
      }],
 "stat": "ok"
}
```

Deserializing  swift code ;

```
if let photos = parsedResult[Constants.FlickerResponseKeys.Photos] as?[String : AnyObject ]{

    //  print(photos[Constants.FlickerResponseKeys.Photo])
    if let photo = photos[Constants.FlickerResponseKeys.Photo] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        print(photo[0])                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this inside photo

```
for (key, value) in photo {
 print(key)
 print(value)
}
```

Comment: bro i understand photo but .. how to mange the [[String : AnyObject]] . where AnyObject mean every object but what is the key ?...   i want to find each String key for each pear

Comment: check my edit this should give you the `String` and `Value`

Comment: nope it is not working .. should throw "  Expression type '[[String : AnyObject]]' is ambiguous without more context" error

Answer (score 0):

You can map your JSON with [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) easily. Create a new swift file and put following code,

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper


class Photos: Mappable  {

var page : Int
var pages : Int
var perpage : Int
var total : Int

var photo : [MyPhoto]

required init?(_ map: Map) {

    page = 0
    pages = 0
    perpage = 0
    total = 0

    photo = []
}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    page                    <- map["photos.page"]
    pages                   <- map["photos.pages"]
    perpage                 <- map["photos.perpage"]
    total                   <- map["photos.total"]

    photo                   <- map["photos.photo"]
  }
}


class MyPhoto: Mappable {

var id : String
var owner : String
var secret : String
.
.
.

required init?(_ map: Map) {

    id = ""
    owner = ""
    secret = ""
}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    id                          <- map["id"]
    owner                       <- map["owner"]
    secret                      <- map["secret"]

}
}
```

And this is how you will use it.

```
if let data = Mapper<Photos>().map(result){
    print(data.perpage)
    print(data.photo.count)
    // do something with your data
}
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty .

Comment: thanks. but i am in new in swift . i do not understand anything about your code .

Comment: No problem if you are new. Go to the link of ObjectMapper and install it using cocoaPods and then follow my answer. And let me know if you stuck someWhere.

Comment: I do not recommend Manuall Mapping of JSON because. If at any point key changes or a key is removed from the json there are chances that your app will crash.